# Is it possible to set default alert style for macOS UNNotification?

Tags: swift, macos, notifications

My application posts local macOS notifications. It's important that these are not `banner` style but `alert` style instead.

So far I have achieved that by setting `NSUserNotificationAlertStyle=alert` in the `Info.plist`.
When a first `NSUserNotification` is sent to the user, he is asked to approve the app's alerts.
Once approved, the App gets `Alert style` set to `Alerts` in the macOS Preferences.

However, the `NSUserNotification` API s deprecated since `macOS 11`.

In the code below I've tried to use the newer `UNNotification` API, the `Alert style` is always set to `banner`
no matter the `NSUserNotificationAlertStyle` property value.

Is there any way to work around that? Since users can change the alert style anyway,
I am not sure why the apps cannot decide on the default style themselves.

```swift
import UserNotifications
import SwiftUI

@main
struct UNNotificationIssuesApp: App {

    init() {
        let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            if granted {
                notificationCenter.getNotificationSettings { settings in
                    print("Granted app notification permissions: \(settings)")
                }
            } else {
                print("All the app's notification permissions were revoked")
            }

            if let err = error {
                print("An error occurred while granting app notification permissions:", err.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Default banner alert style]

Comment: Struggling with the same issue and no solution found yet.

Comment: Had a talk with an Apple engineer. Got a confirmation this is no longer possible and most likely won't be possible in the future either. For some reason, Apple believes it may be harmful if applications decide on the default alert style even though users can override the setting in the System Preferences anyway.

I was recommended to create a notification system of my own if I needed such behaviour. This makes no sense whatsoever though.

Comment: Thanks for the update! So am I correct in assuming that 3rd party devs cannot show persistent alerts anymore unless the user changes it manually?

Comment: Yes. Only the in-built macOS apps can send alerts by default :(